# Why do I get error when I run my xaction file in PUC (Pentaho User Console)?

Tags: pentaho, business-intelligence, kettle, pentaho-design-studio, xaction

I get the below error when I run my xaction file in PUC (Pentaho User Console)

```
The Pentaho BI Platform reported an error while running an action sequence
Possible Causes:
ActionValidationException: RuntimeContext.ERROR_0035 - Action validation failed.
Action Sequence:farzan.xaction
Execution Stack:
EXECUTING ACTION: looking for the current user (KettleComponent)
Loop Index:N/A
```

I have attached xaction, ktr and database at:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxjJ_gZ-RT2EemMtLTlYR1R3TUk&usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your `xaction` file is throwing errors. Best way to find out your errors is to go search the log files. The path would be inside the BA Server: `/pentaho/server/biserver-ee/pentaho-solutions/logs/..` There you will find log file. Check the error that is written in the logs.

*[Also to note, from version 5 onwards, xaction support has been removed from the Pentaho releases.]*

Hope this helps:)

Comment: thank you for answer:)  i have a question in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35307220/how-export-chart-from-ktr-in-bi-server)  please help me about that thank you very much

Comment: @FarzanInstitute If this answer solved your query. Then please kindly accept the answer. It would help in closing this question thread. In the meatime will look into ur other question.